# How can I resume task in the previous thread context after an "await"?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

In Winforms/WPF the following code works:

```
var id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
await DoAsync();
var @equals = id == Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId; //TRUE
```

*I know that `await DoAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)` will resume in another thread*.

However, how can this WinForms/WPF behavior can be accomplished in the, say, Console App? In the console app, the above condition will return **FALSE**, regardless if I use `ConfigureAwait(true/false)`. *My app is not a console, it's just the same behavior*.
I have several classes that implements `IMyInterface` with a method `Task<IInterface> MyMethod()` and in my starting point I need to start in a STA thread, so I create an STA thread like this

```
     public static Task<TResult> Start<TResult>(Func<TResult> action, ApartmentState state, CancellationToken cancellation)
     {
        var completion = new TaskCompletionSource<TResult>();
        var thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                completion.SetResult(action());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                completion.SetException(ex);
            }
        });

        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.SetApartmentState(state);
        if (cancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
            completion.SetCanceled();
        else
            thread.Start();

        return completion.Task;
    }
```

So I must ensure that in every class that implements `IMyInterface` it resumes to the STA thread created in the beginning.

How can one accomplish that?

Comment: You could create your own sync context before you await.

Comment: if you are in an STA context, that indeed sounds like you should be creating your own sync-context that is backed by some kind of work queue and worker loop

Comment: I think your initial assumption is incorrect. "I know that await DoAsync().ConfigureAwait(false) will resume in another thread.".  Does it?

Comment: @rory.ap is there some docs/articles about that?

Comment: Here, [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/) should help.  It gets into creating your own setup about 2/3 of the way down.  FYI, the author Stephen Toub is one of the leading experts on this stuff (indeed, he's a Software Engineer at Microsoft working on .NET), so you can trust whatever he says on the subject.

Comment: @JobaDiniz STA threads *must* pump. I recommend installing a WinForms or WPF Dispatcher loop on an STA thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment above, [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/) is a great resource for answering this question.  The author, Stephen Toub, is one of the leading experts on this stuff (indeed, he's a Software Engineer at Microsoft working on .NET), so you can trust whatever he says on the subject.

Here, I've adapted his example code to accomplish this.  First, derive your own `SynchronizationContext` class:

```
private sealed class SingleThreadSynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<KeyValuePair<SendOrPostCallback, object>> _queue =
        new BlockingCollection<KeyValuePair<SendOrPostCallback, object>>();

    public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state) 
        => _queue.Add(new KeyValuePair<SendOrPostCallback, object>(d, state));

    public void RunOnCurrentThread()
    {
        KeyValuePair<SendOrPostCallback, object> workItem;

        while (_queue.TryTake(out workItem, Timeout.Infinite))
            workItem.Key(workItem.Value);
    }

    public void Complete() => _queue.CompleteAdding();
}
```

Then create a specialized message pump class:

```
public class AsyncPump
{
    public static void Run(Func<Task> func)
    {
        var prevCtx = SynchronizationContext.Current;

        try
        {
            var syncCtx = new SingleThreadSynchronizationContext();
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(syncCtx);
            var t = func();
            t.ContinueWith(delegate { syncCtx.Complete(); }, TaskScheduler.Default);
            syncCtx.RunOnCurrentThread();
            t.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
        finally
        { SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(prevCtx); }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
[STAThread]
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AsyncPump.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
    });

    // We're still on the Main thread!
}
```